# Not able to restart pure-ftp or create new ftp account

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, pureftpd

I had an ubuntu LAMP server setup that had ISPConfig.

I removed ISPConfig and now what I want to do is create a new ftp account for a new website I have setup on the server. My issue is if I do ftp localhost on the CLI  Welcome to Pure-FTPd
I need to I believe restart pure-ftp for the new user account information to take affect but everything i try to do to restart it I get a not found error?

```
sudo /etc/init.d/pure-ftpd restart
```

Gives me a sudo: /etc/init.d/pure-ftpd: command not found message

```
sudo service pure-ftpd restart
```

Gives me a Failed to restart pure-ftpd.service: Unit pure-ftpd.service not found.
message ??

So on an ubuntu 16 Apache2 server how do you restart pure_ftp ?

Comment: First you need to install it. Of course if you had ISPConfig on this thing before, you should blow the whole thing away and reinstall the OS.

Comment: Why would I need to re-install pure_ftp if its already installed?

Comment: Did you install it or did ISPConfig install it? If the latter, you still need to blow it away.

Comment: ISPConfig installed it I then removed ISPConfig because I didn't want it on the server and it was a super old version that wouldn't let me update the PHP version on the server using it.

Comment: But it's still left a bunch of junk around, including an apparently somewhat broken pure-ftpd. Maybe you can reinstall it, but your best bet really is to start fresh.

Comment: So i did a sudo apt-get install pure-ftpd but now when I try to create a ftp user i get You must give (non-root) uid and gid I am trying to create a root ftp user one that has access to all folders inside var/www since this is an internal office server that only myself and one other dev would ftp into.